# Someone forged my resignation letter

Tags: resignation

So about six weeks ago, my mother’s illness took a turn for the worse, and I took some time off work to take care of her. It was all very rushed because we never expected her condition to worsen so quickly and things were just very messy. I was also pretty stressed at the time, so perhaps I didn’t deal with the situation in the best way, and I only communicated with the CEO over the phone about the whole situation and I didn’t know how long I would be away. He was understanding and basically told me to take as much time as I needed.

Anyway, my mother died three weeks later and after the funeral I flew back home. I was still grieving and wanted a bit more time off to work through some emotions. But I wanted to actually come back to work to negotiate in person. To my surprise when I got in (and apparently to everyone else’s surprise as well) my desk had been cleared. I spoke to my CEO and he told / showed me a resignation email I had allegedly sent him. It was actually from my work address. He even showed me his reply email accepting my resignation. It was dated only a few days after I left and he said the paperwork had all been filled out and there was nothing he could do because they already hired someone to replace me.

Now, maybe it could be conceivable to others that, in my grief, I remotely logged in, sent the email and forgot I did it. I know I didn’t send the email (I need a work dongle to log in and I didn’t bring it with me) but I don’t know who would’ve sent it. I can’t imagine my CEO doing something like this. He seemed genuinely surprised that I had come back and he said he had been disappointed to learn that I had decided to move back for good. It could’ve been a colleague because I know there is a backdoor way to send emails using someone else’s account via some sort of a SQL database thing. We used to do it as jokes but it was never used for something like this and I can’t imagine anyone that would hate me enough to go this far.

The fact is, I don’t care that much about the job. It was the fact that I had long service leave in about 6 months (I was actually coming in to negotiate whether I could take the leave early) and quitting meant I wouldn’t be paid out for it.

So I guess in this situation, do I have any choice other than to accept someone quit for me and move on?

Comment: Kumal, what country are you in? It may make a difference for some answers.

Comment: I'm sorry you have to deal with this while dealing with the loss of your mother.

Comment: Discussion about email spoofing, the law, and the CEO's behavior has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59460/discussion-on-question-by-kumal-j-someone-forged-my-resignation-letter).

Comment: There is some definite legal culpability on the company here.  Was the CEO indignant?  I might find myself suspicious of him if there was not a serious wide-eyed response followed by the instant summoning of the head of IT and an immediate investigation into this forgery.

Comment: How long had you worked there?

Comment: Isn't a signature required for such quitting ?

Comment: I see one mistake that I also do  way too often: You start to defend the CEO.

A) You don't know if he did it or not. And even if he didn't he is responsible for you as your boss, and he can still fail by being irresponsible. How was his reaction? Was he considering your situation (i.e. did he offer money or a job)? Did he think this immoral to death and start an investigation immediately? 

B) What is it that YOU need? Mourning for family members is your right. Keeping your job is (probably) your right. Getting paid is your right. If you don't get it automatically someone F's you.
(cont)

Comment: C) The legal situation. Someone did something extremely illegal to you. You don't need to do anything here but a criminal complaint. The law system then starts collecting proof. There should be no cost or hard work for you. And an email is at least in my country no proof exactly because you may have not written it yourself. A signed paper letter is required to resign and a resignation can't be accepted without receiving one. Even accepting the resignation via email is illegal. (at least in my country)

Comment: This story does not make sense.  What CEO would accept an email resignation from an absent person without any further dialogue with the person?  In any case, the CEO is either in on it or criminally negligible.  If this story is true, you need to contact a lawyer and possibly sue for wrongful termination (or whatever law applies in your country).

Comment: FYI This question is currently the top post on Hacker News with some interesting comments. https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=14442971

Comment: Check the email headers, SMTP headers can be spoofed and the headers *could* tell you the origin...

Comment: The email headers should be able to show the computer the email was sent from. Hopefully it's from a system that you don't have access to, with luck it's from the workstation of the person who forged the email. Act quickly before logs get erased.

Comment: Can you please add a country tag, in some countries (France for instance) you do not need to worry, you are still working in your company. A resignation is a much more formal act over here.

Comment: The SQL thing actually makes sense. It's not completely unreasonable for the developers to have somehow obtained the sa password, and it's not unreasonable that the SQL server is running with high enough domain permissions that it could forge email; quite possibly by writing a blob to exchange's queue.

Comment: @kumalJ Do please post an update or accept an answer, when you get a chance.  It would be good to know what happened, and whose answer was closest tot the mark.

Comment: He said there was nothing he could do? That is a lie. He's the CEO. He can void the resignation on the spot and direct reversal of every official action taken.

Answer (score 301):

**You need to talk to a lawyer, ASAP.**

It is absolutely unacceptable that a company would accept a forged resignation. It's understandable for them to have believed it initially, but once you came in to say it wasn't you, an investigation should have started. Whether you want to keep this job or not, it is unethical for them to leave you suddenly unemployed because someone else committed fraud.

Regardless of whether you want to keep the job or not, get a lawyer. (IANAL, so the rest of this is speculative.) At the very least the company owes you severance pay for firing you. It's unlikely you'll get your job back (unless they give you the job of the person who forged your letter), but you have a good chance of getting damages. My guess is the most difficult part would be proving it wasn't you who resigned, as the company would likely accuse you of regretting your resignation and lying about it.

The specifics of what you can hope to achieve are going to be greatly dependent on your local laws, but that's a question for your lawyer, not us.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59566/discussion-on-answer-by-david-k-someone-forged-my-resignation-letter).

Answer (score 75):

I would recommend going to one of the Assistant District Attorneys in your area as a first step. Forgery is a felony in the United States, a serious crime. Your first move should be to find out if the DA would be willing to prosecute a case like this. If they want to prosecute, they will ask you to sign an affidavit swearing to the facts of the case. You may want to bring such an affidavit with you when you go to the DA's office.

If the DA's office says they might be willing to prosecute, then they will tell the police to investigate it further and collect evidence. If a crime is discovered, then you will have the company "by the balls" so to speak, since they fired you fraudulently. Even if the CEO claims he had no idea, it does not matter because it is negligence to fire somebody based on a lone email with no signature or other assurance. If the police investigation reveals that the forgery was part of a conspiracy to fire you, then you will have a huge legal claim against the company (think in hundreds of thousands of dollars).

Either way, step number one: talk to the DA's office and come prepared with a full written statement of the situation.

(PS Comment on lawyers: while talking to a lawyer is certainly possible, in this case you will get better, faster results by going to the DA first. You can always hire a lawyer later. A lawyer might be tempted to steer you down a path that is not in your best interest, but makes more money for them. With a criminal situation such as this, get it going with the DA first, and think about lawyers later after the criminal case is established.)

Comment: This assumes the OP is in the US, which he hasn't specified yet. Definitely a good answer for the US though.

Comment: Well, yes for the amounts, but you will find that in pretty much every jurisdiction forgery is a non trivial crime with jail time attached.

Comment: This answer seems highly speculative. Would it actually be negligent if employer was legitimately unaware and OP is in an at-will employment state with minimal employee rights? Also, average out of court settlement for wrongful termination is $40,000, not hundreds of thousands.

Comment: @JohnStraka The problem is that if forgery is involved it becomes criminal. In that case, the firing becomes a serious civil tort, so a jury will often award "what the employee would have made" had there not been a criminal conspiracy against him. Not only that, but because of the criminal situation damages can be doubled or trebled. Once a crime is involved, the civil damages become much larger. If the company had just fired him without cause, he might have had no claim at all, but since he was potentially deprived of his job due to a criminal conspiracy, it is completely different.

Comment: Above and beyond that, it's a Federal felony if the business has any business outside of the state where it has headquartered itself. Regardless, lawyer. Yesterday.

Comment: "_If a crime is discovered, then you will have the company "by the balls" so to speak, since they fired you fraudulently._" That would completely depend on the location. In most states, employees are at will, unless there is an employment contract. That means that they can be hired or fired for any reason (except federally protected reasons, e.g. race, religion, etc.), or absolutely no reason whatsoever, and an employer in those states doesn't owe an employee any explanation.

Comment: This answer seems best morally. The honest truth is the CEO/company (assuming it wasn't the CEO) is likely just as hurt as you you. (Some say they shouldn't have accepted an email, but paper letters are no less forgeable, so it's the same situation.) They're facing payment of your leave time, perhaps more, yet also paying the new employee. And other than a little poor haste, they're just as victims as you. The one who deserves consequences is the one who broke the law. The only question is whether thats the CEO... if it is, this answers would seem your best hope of avoiding evidence sabotage.

Comment: @JohnStraka : not to mention in some jurisdiction without at will employment, the amout of court liabilities can be capped. In my case they are plans to cap judicial expectation damage at 15,000€ or even slightly less in case of  wrongful termination whatever the reason is and whatever it happened *(one of electoral promise of Emanuel Macron)*.

Comment: @Socrates Why would you have the company by the balls if the company is the victim of a crime?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Because even if the CEO of the company could prove he had no foreknowledge of the fraud (hard to do btw) it doesn't matter because he took advantage of it. Firing somebody on the basis of an email alone is negligent, and because forgery is involved, it becomes criminal negligence which is highly actionable. Any US jury will make a big award in this situation, certainly in the hundreds of thousands, maybe as much as a million or more.

Comment: @Socrates Do you have legal authority  for the statement that accepting a resignation by email alone is negligent?  It's not at all obvious to me that it is.

Comment: The police can definitely find out the IP from where that email was sent. Harder to prove who committed the crime though. But since the crime was committed, I can imagine it was done to avoid paying OP compensation. So suing the company and filing a criminal complaint would be the way to go here.

Comment: @Socrates Even if firing somebody based on an email is negligent (hard to believe in all circumstances, particularly the one described here. What are the alternatives anyhow - would you seriously suggest that the company should force him to fly back so he can hand in his resignation in person? What if he refuses to do so?), why would acting on that forged information suddenly cause *you* to be responsible for the fraud? This seems rather dubious legal advice at best.

Comment: @Voo Look, if you don't like my answer then write your own. I advised the OP based on my understanding of the legal reality and what I believe to be the best course of action. If you have some course of action you think is better, write your own answer.

Comment: @Socrates If you're giving legal advice, be prepared to defend it with more than "hey that's what I think". The first part of your answer is spot on, the remainder seems like poorly sourced assumptions based on no case law to me - but if you have any specific pointers be sure to include it, I could certainly be wrong!. It seems rather important to point that out.

Comment: -1 Loads of assumptions, not least of which is the "OP must be living in _my_ country" assumption. Newsflash: most people don't! There's a whole world out here buddy.

Answer (score 46):

I would try to get a lawyer versed in IT subjects/cybercrime.

What the OP and the other answers seem to ignore is that is rather trivial to spoof email messages; the email protocol was never designed with security in mind. (any IT person worth his salt can easily land in your email box an email "from" Bill Gates "himself" from pretty much anywhere in the world - this is kid´s stuff for any rookie system administrator)

That said, if an investigation is made, getting the full and original email will be essential to find out where that message came from; e.g. a forward copy is not enough.

Looking at the full headers, and or the logs of the email server, or rather saying in a more formal way, a cursory forensic investigation will most probably prove easily the message did not come from the location where you were hosted.

Do not ask beforehand for this data.  Do not alert anyone of this path; let the competent authorities demand this data from them. Otherwise, the culprit might try to cover his tracks.

Comment: To address your email security point, you'd be hard pressed to do that nowadays, especially within the same email system. Exchange doesn't let you send emails from addresses that you don't have rights for, and tools like SPF and DKIM (which a lot of places have configured) prevent you from sending emails from domains which you aren't authorised to do so. What's more likely is that his account password was reset (eg someone rang the helpdesk and pretended to be him). That wasy they could monitor the replies as well in case he did have the dongle with him

Comment: SPF and DKIM have been around for ages now, but just open yout spam folder. Not all places implement it, and still many misconfigured/legacy servers out there.

Comment: OP claims that the e-mail was ostensibly sent from his work e-mail to his superior's work e-mail, so the e-mail would only have gone through the company's internal mail server(s) which should have good in-bound and out-bound records since businesses are typically legally required to keep records of all their correspondence.

Comment: @DavidFoerster So far so good, no one is saying anything contrary to that. The point is in proving now from where and by which method the email was produced. What I was calling attention is that besides the email being produced using the "known backdoor", or by subverting the actual OP account, there also many trivial ways to fake it, and only a proper legal, authorised forensic audit can get to the bottom of the question.

Comment: There are potentially more laws here - using someone else's (work) account will almost definitely be against company rules, and possibly work contracts. There may be local laws about unauthorised computer access that apply too. I'd imagine the forgery is a crime in a lot of jurisdictions too. On another note, it's a pretty crappy boss who accepts a resignation without actually speaking to the person first.

Comment: Indeed...but for that, you have to prove it happened. Since the OP has been shown the email, I would worry about proving I was not at the office at the time the email was sent.

Answer (score 18):

## Hire a lawyer, obviously

It's amusing that so many are saying that the CEO should do something about it.  Seriously?  Who do you think authorized it?

In most email systems, you can't forge an email without the help of IT. Manager can't do it, coworker can't do it and the CEO can't do it.  Do you really think think an IT guy is going to help anyone but the CEO forge an email?  "Charlie, Kumal just quit and I need to get into his account. Change his password for me." and it's done.

But yes, you need to see a lawyer, pronto. **Don't go see your district attorney as a first step though.** That would be self-injurious because a prosecutor isn't interested in you, he's interested in getting a conviction and really couldn't care less whether you get what you deserve.

An attorney that works for **you** is who you want to talk to first of all.  If it's advantageous for you to call the authorities, he'll do that. And that may be the case actually, but you need someone looking out for your interests first and your attorney is the one to do that. **Your attorney could actually possibly use the threat of a criminal complaint as leverage.**

Having said all that, you've got a really tough case which I know you're aware. Having nothing written down hurts you.  On the other hand, any judge or jury would have to find it hard to believe that a person would suddenly quit without even asking for your final paycheck.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59565/discussion-on-answer-by-christopher-estep-someone-forged-my-resignation-letter).

Answer (score 16):

To answer your question bluntly: no; you do not have accept this, **and you shouldn't.**

As many others noted:

## 1) Hire a Lawyer

## 2) Report the fraud to a law enforcement agency

But since no-one has suggested it, yet:

## 3) Contact an IT Professional specializing in Digital Forensics.

If you still have access to your email, back it up to a file and submit it to your lawyer and IT professional as evidence. If you do not have access to the alleged email, your lawyer may subpoena it. Either way, once you have that email deliver it to an IT Forensics professional. **They can use the email header to reverse engineer the IP address of the person who emailed it.** Also consider subpoenaing the mail-server's log.

**Cross reference the time and location with your own records and you can prove fraud.**

*Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer but I am an IT professional (though not forensics).*

Comment: Bingo. Get the raw copy of this e-mail with all the headers and have some expert look at it.

Comment: And: get any/all **logs** from the mail server from around that time.

Comment: I suggested pretty much the same 3 hours before.

Comment: Since you need a dongle to remote-in to your work, I would assume that your access is logged. You (or your lawyer) should request a copy of the access logs for the time-period that the email was sent.
If you didn't log in, it should be good evidence that you didn't send the email.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: That's odd I didn't see it when I posted this; granted I took some time (an hour?) to double check my thoughts before posting. Nevertheless, you're correct. What's the procedure here?

Comment: @KareemElashmawy Do as you see fit. If you think your answer complements mine or brings something new, keep it. If you something else to improve mine, you are welcome too.

Answer (score 10):

I'm terrified that one can quit without a handwritten signature on real paper (or official e-signature of some kind). As other answers state, you need to contact a lawyer.

It is highly likely that your resignation is not legally sound. Your employer should be easy to convince to pay you the leave and avoid expensive lawsuits. Just don't sign anything without your lawyer!

Whether you want to go after the one sending your resignation letter, that's your own decision - is it worth it? Maybe it is. You decide if you want to put energy into it. But if your CEO is serious, they will most definitely want to get rid of such a person and will try to find who that was.

Answer (score 6):

I would discuss with your superior what has happened and make clear that you did not send this mail. It is not ok (from a security and personal point) that this can happen. First discuss it with him before making accusations or start searching for the culprit.

Secondly I would decide what you would like to do. Do you want to return to the job, or use this as an opportunity to change? This is completely up to you.

Comment: yeah as I specified, I already discussed it with him but there's nothing can be done cause the paperwork is filled in and they've hired someone else. I don't really mind so much about losing the job as I need time to clear my head - I'm just not happy about losing my long service leave :(

Comment: Maybe nothing can be done about your job, but it would surprise me if this would not  be an issue. Securitywise, this is absolutely not a good situation. 

If you would like your leave, I suggest reading up on your rights in your specific country and mentioning this to your boss. Maybe you can have your leave, and your leave would only be activated after this.

This is your company at fault, not you. However, you might need to go to court to get what you want.

Comment: @KumalJ If you answer that way you're not making it clear what you want. The fact is, you didn't intend to quit and you want something to be done ("nothing can be done" is not acceptable). You might suggest that if they pay the long service leave that you would be due in a few months, that you would find that acceptable. Consider hiring a lawyer if you want to show you're serious.

Comment: Perhaps get back in touch with the CEO or other superior asking for a copy of the email at least, as you don't remember it, and want to refresh yourself???

Comment: @JeopardyTempest do *not* say that you don't remember it. Because that opens the door for you having done it and forgotten.

Comment: Ok, indeed, better careful wording may be in order (though the door you could have done it and forgotten it will always be open in their minds)

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the USA, call the local law enforcement agency that handles Fraud and Forgeries.  They will probably tell you it is a Civil matter, however, in which case you need a lawyer as others have suggested.

Depending upon where you are located, it could be First or Second Degree Forgery, typically a Felony.

And yes, I'd call the local law enforcement folks first, Sheriff's Office/Department or Police Department, County or Municipality or both.  They will direct you to the Investigators and/or Detectives (at least in the USA.)

At the same time, I'd call a lawyer and tell them I had called and opened a criminal case.

When law enforcement starts calling the employer, you might find out real quick if it is made up or not, unless someone wants to go to jail.

But, just how much emotional capital are you willing to spend?  It could be a nightmare.  Crimes usually are.

Be **sure** you are right on this before you start.  It could turn into a **much** bigger mess than it already is.  Think about what you will tell new employers in the Interview (Oh, my last job, well I put a guy in jail and sued the company.)

Comment: In the USA, a tortious  forgery is NOT merely a civil matter, even if a policeman (wrongly) says so.

Comment: Um, no.  It's not forgery. That involves signatures or writings of some kind. I realize it feels like forgery because someone impersonated him, but it's fraud. Having lived with a detective and known many detectives, the chances of him getting anything more than a report taken and a phone call made is pretty slim. That's why a lawyer first is better because they can subpoena just as easily as a cop can ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a bit of good advice suggesting you should check with a lawyer.  Whether you were wronged in a legally liable way will vary based on laws in your area.  Such laws may vary based on your employer, like how big of a company it is.  For "at will" employment, the company may not have been required to keep your job open at all.

You may want to see if you can negotiate being paid for the long service leave, as the company might prefer to pay you what the company was probably intending to pay you soon anyway (instead of risk a court case that might lead to greater damages).  You may want to assess how likely you think you'd win in court, what your favorable judgement would likely be, and how much you would care about the idea that you may be burning bridges (being unlikely to ever be re-hired after launching such a suit... although, how likely is a near-term opening for such a position anyway?)

If you do decide to take the friendly approach of trying to communicate directly with a friendly CEO (instead of starting out by lawyering up), make sure any "settlement" includes you getting a copy of the relevant log information (especially what IP addresses were involved, and any details on who those IP addresses may have been assigned to).  Get that data preserved ASAP.  If you don't ask for this right away, the company may not be inclined to help you (an ex-employee) have data you could use to sue the jerk who did this (a current employee), even if their internal investigation identified who did this atrocity.

Regardless of your immediate thoughts about when to get a lawyer involved, definitely document details immediately.  Who did what, who said/typed what, and when?  Such details can fade over time, perhaps especially as more details are added, and so having written records (even self-created ones) can be extremely valuable.

Also, before taking any aggressive/hurtful actions against the company or the person who wrote that E-Mail, consider how much you want to try to personally profit, how much you want to inflict justice, and how much you want to mercifully forgive.  A lot of people just default to trying to get whatever seems easily apparent that they might be able to get, such as money and trying to get whatever emotional satisfaction revenge seems like it might offer.  However, pursuing such acquisitions can have some costs (including emotional toll) and such pursuit isn't always the best route.  Intentionally make your decision.  (Coming to a decision of your own will is at least likely to help you to feel less like a complex situation gained power over you, leaving you unable to, at minimum, even make your own decisions.)

Comment: If the OP worked at a company (and location) that falls under FMLA, they would in fact have been required to keep his job open for him.

Comment: @stannius : I did say "Such laws may vary based on your employer, like how big of a company it is."  [Wikipedia's article on the FMLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_and_Medical_Leave_Act_of_1993) notes "work at a location where the company employs 50 or more employees".  That excludes a whole lot of employers.  The reports that the CEO made this change (he didn't speak to HR), and the state of E-Mail security, both suggest a higher likelihood of a less bureaucratically run organization than the experiences I've had with FMLA-encumbered employers.

Comment: Sorry, I missed those words, carry on!